# "Incorrect" information from boost::stacktrace

Tags: c++, linux, boost, stack-trace

In my program under Linux, in one of the functions, for academic purposes, a null pointer was dereferenced. Before this dereference, the stack trace is printed to standard output.

```
// -std=c++17 -ldl -g -O2 -DBOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE -rdynamic
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ns {
struct Type {};
} // namespace ns

template <typename T> T zoo() {
  auto st = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
  std::cout << st << std::endl;
  int *p = nullptr;
  std::cout << *p;
  return T{};
}

int boo() {
  zoo<ns::Type>();
  return 42;
}

void foo() { boo(); }

void doo() { foo(); }

int main() { doo(); }
```

When the program is run, this is displayed in the console:

```
0# boost::stacktrace::basic_stacktrace<std::allocator<boost::stacktrace::frame> >::size() const at /usr/etc/boost_1_80_0/boost_release/include/boost/stacktrace/stacktrace.hpp: 215
1# main in ./a.out
2# __libc_start_main in /lib64/libc.so.6
3# _start in ./a.out
```

However, if you look at the core dump, it provides richer information:

```
#0 zoo<ns::Type> () at main.cc:16
#1 0x0000000000402299 in boo() at main.cc:20
#2 foo() at main.cc:22
#3 doo () at main.cc:27
#4 main() at main.cc:32
```

The program is compiled with debug symbols. How to "force" boost::stacktrace to output information like a core dump?

Comment: RTFM? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am defining the BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE macro. And it works, but in the core dump I see the entire call stack, and the stacktrace does not show the functions doo, foo and boo.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9h9rb7q6P